# How do I store code in Craft

Tags: fieldtypes

I need to store Javascript/HTML code in some of our entries. I have tried to put the code in plaintext but cannot get the code to render through twig. I cannot store this stuff on the filesystem. It really needs to be attached to an entry if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are a few plugins which make adding code to entries a nicer experience... Check out [Ace Freely](https://github.com/httpster/Ace-Freely) or [Code Block](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-codeblock).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store it in a plaintext field, then when you output it, do: `{{ entry.myfield | raw }}`